# Dynamically generate a form?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have about 10 different objects that get populated from user input. Instead of creating 10 different view pages, is there a way to dynamically generate the input form and have only one view page? What I am looking for is a run-time solution like the form generator in visual studio when you "Add View".

Comment: Did you look at http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<%=Html.EditorForModel() %>` will use reflection to generate form fields for all the properties on an object. You can just use a base class(object) as your model and pass your object in from the controller.